# call soap webservice in android

Tags: android, web-services

I am calling soap Web service in android but response is coming only anyType{}. But response data is not coming. it is only giving that much response how to get response data also.

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/IService1/FindEmployee";
            private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";    
            private static String METHOD_NAME = "FindEmployee"; 
            private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.9/Employee/Service1.svc?wsdl";
            private TextView tv;

            StringBuilder sb;

            private XmlSerializer writer;
            private TextView lblResult1;


             @Override
             public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.main);

              lblResult1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 
              request.addAttribute("Empid", "R001");

              SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
              envelope.dotNet=true;
              envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
              try {
                  androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                 SoapObject resultsRequestSOAP = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
               lblResult1.setText(resultsRequestSOAP.toString());
               } catch (Exception e) 
               {

               System.out.println("Error"+e);
              }

             }
```

Comment: use addProperty instead of addAtribute in line  request.addAttribute("Empid", "R001");

Comment: try to change request.addProperty("Empid", "R001"); instead of request.addAttribute("Empid", "R001");

Comment: which webservice you are using it it java based or .net baesd

Comment: HttpTransportSE where can i get this class ??

Answer (score 0):

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);
            request.addProperty("Empid", "R001");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            AndroidHttpTransport androidHttpTransport = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);
            androidHttpTransport
            .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(newSoapAction, envelope); 
            InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(androidHttpTransport.responseDump.getBytes());    
    System.out.println("WS >>  Response: "+androidHttpTransport.responseDump); // you will get response overhere
```

Comment: `AndroidHttpTransport` is deprecated use `HttpTransportSE`

Comment: i am not getting response data i am just getting result: 06-11 11:41:43.687: W/result(450): <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><FindEmployeeResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><FindEmployeeResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Myservice" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/></FindEmployeeResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Answer (score 0):

just write this  `lblResult1.setText(resultsRequestSOAP.getProperty(0).toString());`

instead of `lblResult1.setText(resultsRequestSOAP.toString());`

may it will help you.

If it is not working it means your webservice not returning any response i.e your web service not getting data from database.

Please write me if you want more help regarding this.